# Laravel query builder - автоматическая сортировка ID

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Есть массив ID'шек постов, отсортированных по количеству поставленных "звезд":

```
[0 => 469
 1 => 470
 2 => 91
 3 => 11]
```

Когда я пытаюсь выполнить запрос:

```
\DB::table('table')
    ->whereIn('id', $id)
    ->take($count)
    ->paginate(12);
```

Массив автоматически сортируется, т.е. ID становятся в порядке возрастания (ASC, смысл от вывода самых популярных пропадает).

Как можно сделать такой запрос с дальнейшей пагинацией?

Comment: От куда массив этот берёте? Если запросом то лучше бы сразу и информацию брать

Comment: Массив беру из таблицы, в которой хранится количество лайков и название модели, далее вытаскиваю ID постов нужной модели в порядке убывания лайков.

Answer (score 1):

В конструкторе запросов можно свободно задавать поле и порядок для сортировки:

```
->orderBy('имя_столбца_в_котором_количество_звёзд', 'desc')
```